# Sended Array is not recieved properly in ROS. Somehow the content gets quantized

Tags: python, ros

I have a topic which generates a trajectory. This trajectory is pusblished using a custom message which contains y and x coordinates in a dynamic float array. My problem is, that the sended trajectory never gets published properly. Instead a very low resolution trajectory with the same lenght gets published when I watch it with `rostopic echo /trajectory/ebike`.

When I print the values of `position_vector_y` and `position_vector_x` right before publishing I can see that they aren't the same as the one I can see with `rostopic echo /trajectory/ebike`.

I use ROS melodic.

**Trajectory.msg**

```
######################################################
# trajectory.msg
######################################################
# ROS timestamp etc.
######################################################
Header header

######################################################
# Position 
######################################################
float32[] m_predicted_x_coordinates_f32
float32[] m_predicted_y_coordinates_f32
```

**calcTray.py**

```
import rospy
from ebike_msgs.msg import Trajectory

ebike_traj = Trajectory()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize node
    rospy.init_node("trajectory_prediction_node")

    # create publisher
    pub_trajectory_ebike = rospy.Publisher('trajectory/ebike', Trajectory, queue_size=1)

    # define the frequency for publishing the data
    config_frequency = rospy.get_param('frequency', 20)
    rate = rospy.Rate(config_frequency)
    
    # run
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        # does some calculation

        # publish Trajectory
        ebike_traj.m_predicted_y_coordinates_f32 = position_vector_y 
        ebike_traj.m_predicted_x_coordinates_f32 = position_vector_x
        pub_trajectory_ebike.publish(ebike_traj)

        rate.sleep()
```

Comment: Where is ```position_vector_y ``` set?

Comment: In the code right above where the comment ```# does some calculation``` is. An example fpr ```position_vector_y``` would be ```[8.924895286560059, 8.924894332885742, 8.924894332885742, 8.924893379211426]```. I send it as a list but it gets automatically received as a tuple. Dunno why but it would be okay if the content woudl'nt been altered.

Comment: Try to copy the content of the array to a new one instead of just setting the reference. Maybe the content is overwritten before it was sent.